# The sequence of calling the two method: updateConstraints and updateViewConstraints in IOS AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

i was told that: "When you tell Auto Layout that the constraints for a view need to be refreshed, by calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` or `updateConstraintsIfNeeded`, it first calls `updateConstraints` on that view, followed by `updateViewConstraints` on the corresponding view controller."
but i have test,the result is first calls `updateViewConstraints`,is there something wrong to me?

Comment: No you're ok, you were misinformed.

Comment: ok,At the beginning i think that i omit some conditions to test it